# URL with question mark gives page not found

Tags: url, contao

I have a problem with URL that involves a question mark, on one particular website.

If you click on this link http://granovino.de/?k
It will give a page not found.

But it's not the case on other websites such as this http://annaline.net/?k

I'm wondering why and how to solve this problem? What should I look into? The website is built by Contao, if it matters.

Thanks,
Andre

Comment: Please learn about query strings

Comment: Thanks for a little hint. Could you be more precise? Btw, why was my question voted down? Because it's a stupid question? I'm not sulking, just an honest curiosity. I'm new here.

Comment: Your question was down-voted as one would easily find this topic on google, thus making it a very general and common question to ask

Comment: Oh I know, what the question mark is used for. My question was really, why one website gives a "page not found", while the other doesn't. My guess it would be some server setup. Not knowing what is called, it's difficult to google. Now that I know its technical term (query strings), I can try to google that.

Comment: Yes. It is the site developers choice not to allow query strings. Please have a look at my edit and accept and up-vote my answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

The problem indeed lies with the query string. Contao checks if there are unused $_GET variables (meaning that no code within the system is checking for the variable) and if so, determines that the URL is not valid and throws a 404.

In the Contao 3 core this check is done in the `FrontendTemplate->output()` method.

This issue was discussed at length [on GitHub here.](https://github.com/contao/core/issues/4277) (Mostly in German)

In order to make the URL valid some part of the code must call `Input::get('xxx')` to mark the query string variable as "used" within the system.

Answer (score 0):

So here goes a brief tutorial about Query Strings

Quoting fro Wikipedia: ***In the World Wide Web, a query string is the part of a uniform resource locator (URL) that contains data to be passed to web applications***

Query String is one of the technique to pass data from one page of the application to another. Consider them as variables being passed from one page to another. Everything followed by the question mark(?) in the URL is a part of the Query string.

A typical example of the URL containing Query String would be

http://www.sample-url@priorqurystring.com/?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3

or if it contains sub-sites, then:

http://www.sample-url@priorqurystring.com/subsite1/default.php?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3

The Query string in the above URL's would be

***field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3***

Now this query string corresponds to 3 fields(variables) having the corresponding values.

At the server side of your application; for that particular page, you may access the query string fields to get the corresponding values and work upon those values to get desired results.

For further info, please refer [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Looking at your concern, The developers of the website must have decided to handle the query string in that manner and must be redirecting to "Page not Found". Maybe they are manipulating some query strings on the page and if the find an incorrect one, they redirect you to the error page.